# function to convert text strings for Sweave files

Tags: r, sweave

I recognised that there are a lot of problems with Sweave and formatting text. I read a lot of questions and answers but I am still not able to solve my problem.

What I would love to do is create variable with some text and then using a function to convert this text (mainly escape the underscores) and use it in \Sexpr{} environment.

I created a short test script, but I couldn't get it to work:

```
sample_id <- 'CF_0123'
sample_id2 <- 'CF\\_0123'
sample_id4 <- 'CF\\\\_0123'
sample_id2b <- gsub('_','\\_',sample_id)
sample_id4b <- gsub('_','\\\\_',sample_id)
sample_id6b <- gsub('_','\\\\\\_',sample_id)

addBackslash <- function(x) {
  return(gsub('_','\\\\_',x))
}

Sweave('SILAC.Rnw')
tools::texi2dvi('SILAC.tex', pdf = TRUE)
```

It only works for the sample_id4 and the code chunk. But in the code chunk it produces new lines and other tags I don't want.

Is there a way to define my plain text within the R script and convert it in a way, so my sweave file uses the text and data from the R script.

My Sweave document SILAC.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\Sexpr{sample_id}
\Sexpr{sample_id2}
\Sexpr{sample_id4}
\Sexpr{sample_id2b}
\Sexpr{sample_id4b}
\Sexpr{sample_id6b}

\Sexpr{addBackslash(sample_id)}
\Sexpr{(cat(gsub('_','\\\\_',sample_id)))}
test


test2
<<forward, echo=FALSE>>=
  cat(gsub('_','\\\\_',sample_id))
@
test3

\end{document}
```

And the resulting .tex file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\input{SILAC-concordance}
CF_0123
CF_0123
CF\_0123
CF_0123
CF_0123
CF_0123

CF_0123
\Sexpr{(cat(gsub('_','\\\\_',sample_id)))}
test


test2
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Soutput}
CF\_0123
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
test3

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the text and text processing R code in the chunk itself and do not need to use `\Sexpr`.

The comments and newline could be suppressed by appropriate `knitr` chunk options `comment=NA`,`results=asis` and `eval=TRUE`

```
require(knitr)
```

**Rnw File:**
Save as (knitr_newline.Rnw)

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

test


test2

<<chunk1,message=FALSE,eval=TRUE,results='asis',echo=FALSE,comment=NA>>=

sample_id <- 'CF_0123'
sample_id2 <- 'CF\\_0123'
sample_id4 <- 'CF\\\\_0123'
sample_id2b <- gsub('_','\\_',sample_id)
sample_id4b <- gsub('_','\\\\_',sample_id)
sample_id6b <- gsub('_','\\\\\\_',sample_id)

addBackslash <- function(x) {
    return(gsub('_','\\\\_',x))
}

 cat(gsub('_','\\\\_',sample_id))
@
test3


\end{document}
```

**Generate PDF:**

```
knit2pdf('knitr_newline.Rnw')
```

**Output:**

[image]

Is this the output you were looking for, let us know...

Comment: What I need is some inline text conversion. Like the CF_0123 should be within some fixed text... Thats why I tried to use Sexpr.
If I use code chunks there is always some "chunk" \begin{Schunk}
\begin{Soutput}
CF\_0123
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk} around my text...